# Add function to NSManagedObject class

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I' ve a Size class generated from Xcode for my size model, here it is:

```
@objc(Size)
public class Size: NSManagedObject {
    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    }
}

extension Size {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Size> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Size>(entityName: "Size")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: Int16
    @NSManaged public var name: String?

    var quantity: Int

    func setQuantity() {}  
}
```

Quantity var and setQuantity method are not accessible from my ViewController though I put public before their declaration, some suggestion?

Comment: you can not declare stored properties in class extension in above code var quantity is a stored property.

Comment: It gives the same error also if I put the variable and the method in the class @MuhammadWaqasBhati

Comment: You need to give some initial value to stored property, then it will work. e.g  var quantity: Int = 0

Comment: It continues to give me "Value of type 'Size' has no member 'quantity'" @MuhammadWaqasBhati

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting the compiler error: `Extensions must not contain stored properties`

You should update it and put the variable to your class instead of to extension.

```
public class Size: NSManagedObject {
     var quantity: Int
     // Same for other variables.
     // Your existing code goes here.
}
```

Try and share your results.